# Conditional subscription to listener in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, service-provider, laravel-events

I have set up a listener by adding it in `EventServiceProvider`

```
protected $subscribe = [
  MyListener::class
];
```

The listener (`MyListener`) has a `subscribe` function that subscribes to the events the listener wants to listen for - **and it works fine**.

---

Now, I'm trying to add a check to restrict which events should be listened to. Something like

```
public function subscribe($events)
{
    $config = ConfigService::getUserConfig();

    if ($config->shouldSubscribe) {
       $events->listen(.....);
    }
}
```

I'm having some issues after adding this logic however.

It seems that when running `composer install` it executes the subscribe method.

This causes an issue, because there is no active session when running `composer install` - so I'm met with a SQL error - it can't find which database to search for configuration in - followed by this error

> Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

**How can I conditionally subscribe to certain events in the listener?**

Answer (score 1):

It is not the exact response for your answer, but it should work in your case. You can detect if your code is running from console by using Application::runningInConsole() function.

Example:

```
public function subscribe($events)
{
    // Running from cli script, abort ship!
    if(app()->runningInConsole())
    {
        return;
    }

    $config = ConfigService::getUserConfig();

    if ($config->shouldSubscribe) {
       $events->listen(.....);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good idea, but runningInConsole also blocks regular artisan commands, where I would still want them subscribed. I wonder if there is a way to only block "composer" things

Comment: Could you send me output of this code when running composer install?
```var_dump($argv);```
First element should be the name of script. If I'm thinking correct it should be composer.